# Thunderbird unable to set Text Encoding to Turkish

Tags: email, thunderbird, encoding

I am using Ubuntu [19.10](/questions/tagged/19.10) and Thunderbird 68.4.1 (64-bit).

I want to set the default **Text Encoding** for incoming mails to **Turkish (ISO-8859-9)**. However, when I go to **Preferences** → **Display** → **Formatting** → **Fonts & Colors: Advanced...** → **Text Encoding**, I cannot see  **Turkish (ISO-8859-9)** in the drop-down list of **Incoming Mail**.

Can you test it in your own installation and see whether you have the same problem or not?

**Notes:**

Output of `apt --installed list | grep -i thunderbird` is:

```
thunderbird-gnome-support/eoan-updates,eoan-security,now 1:68.4.1+build1-0ubuntu0.19.10.1 amd64 [installed]
thunderbird-locale-en-gb/eoan-updates,eoan-updates,eoan-security,eoan-security,now 1:68.4.1+build1-0ubuntu0.19.10.1 all [installed]
thunderbird-locale-en-us/eoan-updates,eoan-updates,eoan-security,eoan-security,now 1:68.4.1+build1-0ubuntu0.19.10.1 all [installed]
thunderbird-locale-en/eoan-updates,eoan-security,now 1:68.4.1+build1-0ubuntu0.19.10.1 amd64 [installed]
thunderbird-locale-tr/eoan-updates,eoan-security,now 1:68.4.1+build1-0ubuntu0.19.10.1 amd64 [installed]
thunderbird/eoan-updates,eoan-security,now 1:68.4.1+build1-0ubuntu0.19.10.1 amd64 [installed]
```

Output of `check-language-support --show-installed -l tr` is:

```
firefox-locale-tr hunspell-tr language-pack-gnome-tr language-pack-tr libreoffice-help-tr libreoffice-l10n-tr poppler-data thunderbird-locale-tr
```

Comment: Is the corresponding locale package installed? For Turkish, it should be something like `thunderbird-locale-tr`. You might want to use the commandline tool `check-language-support` to find out which packages you need. For example, `check-language-support -l tr` gives me the list of `firefox-locale-tr language-pack-gnome-tr language-pack-tr libreoffice-help-tr libreoffice-l10n-tr thunderbird-locale-tr`. Installing those packages should give you a Turkish locale in Thunderbird, Firefox and so on.

Comment: Thank you for the comment @HenningKockerbeck . Although the command `check-language-support -l tr` returns an empty line, the command `apt install thunderbird-locale-tr` returns: `thunderbird-locale-tr is already the newest version (1:68.4.1+build1-0ubuntu0.19.10.1).`

Comment: I think the correct version of your command should be `check-language-support --show-installed -l tr`, whose answer I have added to my OP.

Comment: I don't have it too (same thunderbird version on 18.04)

Comment: Could not get Turkish running either :(